# Get post value in controller empty array

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform

I am getting empty array in post in admin form.

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost()
```

It was working fine before I have updated 3 more fields to this form field like below:

```
$fieldset->addField("meta_title", "text", array(
                        "label" => Mage::helper("modulename")->__("Meta Title"),
                        "name" => "meta_title",
                        ));

                        $fieldset->addField("meta_description", "textarea", array(
                        "label" => Mage::helper("modulename")->__("Meta Description"),
                        "name" => "meta_description",
                        ));

                        $fieldset->addField("meta_keyword", "text", array(
                        "label" => Mage::helper("modulename")->__("Meta Keyword"),
                        "name" => "meta_keyword",
                        ));
```

Comment: Have you tried Mage::app()->getRequest()?

Comment: Yes i have tried it but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got blank array in post due to some misconfiguration of .htaccess rule

I have changed my .htaccess with fresh one it solved my problem

may be it will helpful to someone.

Comment: Can you please let me know what change the htaccess file have ?